# Вытащить массив из postgresql

Tags: массивы, postgresql, golang

Сейчас я реализовано так:

```
package main

import (
"database/sql"
"fmt"

"strings"
"time"

_ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func main() {
var err error
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "host=localhost port=5433 user=admin    password=Oma524744 dbname=Role sslmode=disable")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Postgresql not found!:", err)
}

if err = db.Ping(); err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Postgresql not reply!:", err)
}
Results := make([]string, 0)
Rows, err := db.Query("SELECT  \"Name\"  FROM \"Test\" WHERE id=$1;", 1)
for Rows.Next() {
    var tmp string
    Rows.Scan(&tmp)
    t1 := time.Now()
    tmp = tmp[1 : len(tmp)-1]
    fmt.Println(tmp)
    Results = strings.Split(tmp, ",")
    t2 := time.Now()
    fmt.Println("::->", t2.Sub(t1).Nanoseconds())
}
for _, v := range Results {
    fmt.Println(v)
}
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

}
```

А потом мне еще преобразовывать все в числа float64, можно ли как то считать значения с бд напрямую в срез?

Структура БД:

```
CREATE TABLE "Test"
 (
   id integer,
   "Name" numeric[]
 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В модуле `github.com/lib/pq` есть тип [`Float64Array`](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#Float64Array):

```
Results := pq.Float64Array{}
row := db.QueryRow("SELECT  \"Name\"  FROM \"Test\" WHERE id=$1;", 1)
err = row.Scan(&Results)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
for _, v := range Results {
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

При этом надо помнить, что `numeric` и `float64` - не одно и то же, и может быть потеря точности.